# Custom designed menu/popup for PySide system tray application

Tags: python, pyqt, cross-platform, pyside, system-tray

I need to create a system tray Application with custom menu/popup using PySide. I could only find docs to create simple menu entry for system tray application. Can someone lead me to any example or doc regarding this, or is there a better technique/tools to achieve the same ? I need the application to work cross platform.

Please see the image below for reference.

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787426/custom-qt-qmenu for some ideas.

Comment: Thanks @three_pineapples, will try that. Hope I am in the right path :)